# C++. Включение и линковка скомпилированных файлов в работающий экземпляр программы

Tags: c++, dll, компоновщик, so

Сразу скажу, с С++ знаком около 2-х месяцев.

Разрабатываю 2D игровой движок (на либах SFML+Box2D с инклюдом JSON & ImGUI). Под конец разработки встал вопрос о разработке различных проектов (игр) на одном экземпляре движка. Решение, конечно, прямое - ядро движка в виде динамической библиотеки. Редактор - приложение на основе этого ядра.

И здесь встал вопрос о том, как в рантайме редактора получить возможность использования скомпилированного файла (скрипта, так же C++)? И верно ли думать, что если динамическая библиотека ядра загружена в памяти, то запуск скрипта, некоторым образом линкующего к ядру (и к его некоторой базе знаний о скриптах) даст нужный эффект в редакторе (который линкуется к этой же копии ядра в RAM)?

OS Linux, compiler g++ last, C++ cxx17.

Comment: Если Вы понимаете, то делаете, то даже не самый последний g++ решит все проблемы. Если же нет, то не имеет значение ни версия gcc, ни версия операционной системы.

Comment: Это просто уточнение версии компилятора и ОС. Потому что, вот уж чудо, под виндой есть свои фишки. Так что, суть вашего комментария не вижу.

Comment: Вам нужно аккуратно переписать вопрос. То, что Вы пишете, можно сделать. Но, библиотека, загруженная в память, не будет так просто делить между разными исполнимыми файлами данные. А вот код - будет.

Comment: Такой вопрос скорее от непонимания того, что нужно сделать, только результат.